# Error importing BERT: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'Optimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, bert-language-model

I tried to use `bert-tensorflow` in Google Colab, but I got the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import  bert
>   ----> 2 from bert import run_classifier_with_tfhub # run_classifier
>         3 from bert import optimization
>         4 from bert import tokenization
>
> 1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bert/optimization.py
>   in ()
>        85 
>        86 
>   ---> 87 class AdamWeightDecayOptimizer(tf.train.Optimizer):
>        88   """A basic Adam optimizer that includes "correct" L2 weight decay."""
>        89
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute
>   'Optimizer'

Here is the code I tried:

1. Install the libraries:

`!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
!pip install tensorflow_hub
!pip install sentencepiece
!pip install bert-tensorflow`

2. Run this code:

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import  bert
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization`

I've also tried 
`import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

But got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some experimentation in my own colab notebook (please provide a link next time) and I found that in the error message, there was

```
class AdamWeightDecayOptimizer(tf.train.Optimizer):
```

this being the header of the class. But there is nothing like `tf.train.optimizer` instead it should be :

```
class AdamWeightDecayOptimizer(tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer):
```

The link where there is exact issue with (lol) exact same line is [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/934)

Comment: thanks, @neel for the answer, I've already checked the link before asking this question, as you can see in the [last comment](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/934#issuecomment-605388753), the issue is not solved yet.

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri what is the error after doing what I posted?

Comment: I've got another error on `run_classifier` like `tensorflow object has no attribute FLAGS`, I understood that it is a compatibility problem when I change to `tf.compat.v1` but it's also failing when I just do `import tensorflow`. I got confused :/

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri we cannot help you if you do not post the whole error traceback....

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been reported and discussed on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30092) as well,

Try to change the code of line 87 (see your error message: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bert/optimization.py), from

```
tf.train.Optimizer
# change to
tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer
```

Are you in TF 1.x or TF 2.0? In general, `tf.train.Optimizer` has been deprecated in TF 2.0, and you need to use `tf.compat.v1.Optimizer` (then the deprecation message shows up but it's a warning only). In TF 2.0, the Keras optimziers [`tf.keras.optimizers.*`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers) are recommended to use.

Answer (score 3):

`import tensorflow as tf`

`print(tf.__version__)`

`!pip uninstall tensorflow==2.2.0`

`!pip install tensorflow==1.15.0`

`!pip install bert-tensorflow`

try this. it worked for me for the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue in google colab by installing tensorflow 1.15 instead of 2.0. I get a warning only.

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```